html2canvas ignores mat-label since material 15
I use html2canvas for creating a pdf-documunent. Since material version 15 the mat-label in the form-field is not visible in the pdf anymore.
This is the usual structure of form-field with label:
 <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>{{ 'CONTRACT_DIALOG.BOOKING_DATE' | translate }}</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    type="text"
    formControlName="bookingDate"/>
 </mat-form-field>


This are my dependencies:
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "jspdf": "2.1.1",

I tried to update html2canvas and jspdf to newest version, but it didn't change anything.

